# Silverlight - GestureService & GestureListner in code-behind

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to do the following XAML code in code behind and not sure how to add the GestureService and GestureListner onto the Image.

Xaml code:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="img" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener/>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

Code behind equivalent:

```
Image image = new Image();
//how do I add GestureService and GestureListner?
ContentPanel.Children.Add(image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
GestureService.GetGestureListener(image);
```

Normal approach would be doing it this way:

```
GestureService.SetGestureListener(image, new GestureListener());
```

But GetstureService developers have marked SetGestureListener method as obsolete:
"Do not add handlers using this method. Instead, use GetGestureListener, which will create a new instance if one is not already set, to add your handlers to an element."